# How do I price OANDA box options?

Tags: option-pricing, software

How do I price OANDA box options without using their slow and 
machine-unfriendly user interface?:

- http://fxtrade.oanda.com (free demo account) sells "box options":

  - If you already know what a box option is (or visit 
    http://fxtrade.oanda.com/trade-forex/fxtrade/box-options or signup 
    for a free demo account), you can skip the rest of this section.
  - A box option is a highly flexible binary option where you choose 
    a FOREX currency pair, a price range and a time range. You win if 
    the FOREX currency pair hits the price range sometime during the 
    time range.
  - Here's how a box option looks on a chart on OANDA's user interface: [image]
  - And the same box option in a form: [image]
  - In the above example, you're betting that USDCAD will trade 
    between 0.98758 and 0.99674 sometime between 1455 and 2000 
    GMT. Note that USDCAD does not have remain in this range the 
    entire time: if USDCAD plunged to 0.98000 before 1455 but then 
    rebounded to 0.98760 at 1900 (or any time between 1455 and 2000), 
    you still win.
  - $1000, the purchase price, is the most you can lose.
  - If you win, OANDA will pay back `$1005.48` for a profit of 
    `$5.48`. This isn't much, because it's fairly likely that you'll 
    win.
  - You can also buy an option betting the exact opposite: that 
    USDCAD won't trade between 0.98758 and 0.99674 *any* time between 
    1455 and 2000 (in other words, USDCAD remains below 0.98758 from 
    1455 to 2000, or remains above 0.99674 from 1455 to 2000).
  - For the opposite option, OANDA pays a little better:[image]

since it's unlikely that USDCAD won't hit that range between 1455 and 2000.

- I'm trying to figure how OANDA prices these options:

  - I'm trying to optimize certain values, so I need quotes for 
    every price range and every time range. It's infeasible to do this 
    using their standard interface. Additionally, it's hard to record 
    values from this user interface into a file.
  - The prices obviously relate in some way to the probability of 
    hitting the time/price range. I know how to calculate these 
    probabilities 
    (https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/box-option-value.m), 
    but can't find a correlation between the probabilities and OANDA's 
    price.
  - OANDA obviously includes a "safety factor" and "commission" in 
    their quotes. If a box option is 50% likely to win, they won't 
    return `$2000` to your `$1000` dollars, since that would mean no profit 
    for them.
  - When the "hit" and "miss" prices are identical (roughly meaning 
    they feel the box option has 50% chance of success), they seem to 
    pay out about `$1400` on a `$1000` bet (meaning a `$400` profit). That's 
    just a rough observation though.
  - This might be more of a project, but I'm looking for help, tips 
    how to get started, brilliant insights, etc.
  - I realize OANDA charges a large "commission" on these options, but still think they can be useful in some cases.

Comment: Raised a question on meta regarding whether this kind of question is appropriate: http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/questions/16/should-questions-related-to-specific-software-be-allow.  Please provide your feedback!

Comment: Yes its appropriate - Why are there so many police mans monitoring questions

Comment: @ChloeRadshaw Because the site is in private beta. The kinds of questions that come up this week will shape the questions that appear on the site when it goes live.

Comment: What model does this software pretends to implement for those box options ? This should be in the documentation and if not I would simply run the "uninstall" and look for another soft.

Comment: @TheBridge The price is calculated on OANDA.COM's servers. I don't know their algorithm and am trying to figure it out. The software I have just talks to OANDA.COM's servers. It doesn't do any calculations itself.

Comment: You could use a GUI automation tool to automate the clicks.

Comment: @Louis That's what I've pretty much done, but there are a LOT of variables, and it'd be nice to find a true formula, not an interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

These are a kind of FX barrier options, look up the models for them. You could even use Blacks model for them. By playing around with strikes, you can test this hypothesis.

Comment: I already have a model for them (https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/box-option-value.m). I just need to see how OANDA's pricing compares to my model.